# End of string becomes start of next string during file writing

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having some issues with writing of output to a file. Suppose I want this format:

```
a1/b1 a2/b2 a3/b3 a4/b4
```

When there is only a single line, there is no problem with the output. However, when I have to do this for multiple lines, I end up with something like this:

```
a1/b1 a2/b2 a3/b3 a4
/b4
c1/d1 ...
```

Here is my code for the appending part:

```
string = ""
for i in range(0, T):
    string = string + a[i] + "/" + b[T-1-i] + " "
    output.write(string + "\n")
```

Comment: what are the contents of the list `a`??and what is `T`??

Comment: @silverhash `a` and `b` refer to lists of strings, `T` is the number of items in `a` (which is equivalent to number of items in `b`).

Comment: you need to post a runnable snippet so we can help you because as it is, this question is unclear and will probably get flagged soon unless you post your code.Another thing,from the code you sent,you are saving one instance per line,i.e for example `a1/b1` on one line `a2/b2` on another so when you say you get `a1/b1 a2/b2 a3/b3 a4`,which code were you using as it is not the code you sent